What's the number of facets of a $d$-dimensional cyclic polytope?
A face of a convex polytope $P$ is defined as

$P$ itself, or
a subset of $P$ of the form $P\cap h$, where $h$ is a hyperplane such that $P$ is fully contained in one of the closed half-spaces determined by $h$.


If $P$ is a polytope of dimension $d$, then its faces have dimensions $-1, 0, 1, \ldots ,d$, where $-1$ is, by definition, the dimension of the empty set. A face
of dimension $j$ is also called a $j$-face.
The $0$-faces are called vertices, the $1$-faces are called edges, and the $( d-1 )$-faces of a $d$-dimensional polytope are called facets.
The curve  $\gamma=\{(t,t^2\ldots,t^d)\mid t\in \mathbb{R}\}$
in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is called the moment curve.
The convex hull of finitely many
points on the moment curve is called a cyclic polytope.

My question is how can I prove that the number of facets of a $d$-dimensional cyclic polytope
with $n$ vertices $(n \geq d+1)$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \binom{n-\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor}{\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor}+ \binom{n-\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor -1}{\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor-1} &\text{for $d$ even,}\\
&\quad\text{ and }\\
\displaystyle 2\binom{n-\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor -1}{\left \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \right \rfloor} &\text{for $d$ odd.}
\end{cases}
?$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope#Gale_evenness_condition

A different approach than using Gale evenness is to note that the polytope is neighborly (i.e., every set of at most d/2 vertices forms a face) so the entries in the first half of the $f$ vector have a very simple formula, and then Dehn--Sommerville determines the entries in the second half: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope#Number_of_faces. Anyways, I think this question is off topic. You can read about this all in any standard polytope source like Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes."

Cross-posted to MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947078/what-is-the-number-of-facets-of-a-d-dimensional-cyclic-polytope
